# How can I get data from post request?

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

What I try to do is to post data from same site and create a new order from it (when the submit button is clicked). I don't have any info in my req.body, I suspect it's in my ejs that went wrong, any feedbacks is much appreciated.

My ejs file:

```
<h1>Orders</h1>

<p>Orders from Coffee eShop.</p>

<pre><%#= JSON.stringify(res, null, 4) %></pre>
<form class="label-left" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Order ID </th>
            <th>Customer ID </th>
            <th>Name </th>
            <th>Date </th>
            <th>Product quantity </th>
            <th>Status </th>
        </tr>
    <% for (const row of res) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= row.order_id %></td>       <!-- trying to post this -->
            <td><%= row.customer_id %></td>    <!-- trying to post this -->
            <td><%= row.customer_name %></td>  <!-- trying to post this -->
            <td><%= row.order_date %></td>     <!-- trying to post this -->
            <td><%= row.produkter_antal %></td><!-- trying to post this -->
            <td><%= row.order_status %></td>   <!-- trying to post this -->
        </tr>
    <% }; %>
    </table>
    <br>
    <td><input type="submit" name="doit" value="Create new order"></td> <!-- trying to get this work -->
    <br><br>
    <a href="/eshop/customer" id="customerlink">Customers</a>
</form>
<br>

<%- include("footer"); %>
```

and my js file:

```
router.get("/order/:id", async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let data = {
        title: `Customers order ${id} ${sitename}`,
        ordernummer: id
    }

    data.res = await bank.showCustomerOrder(id);

    res.render("eshop/order", data);
});

router.post("/order/:id", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    // this doesnt work... I dont get any info in req.body here
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; how are you trying to POST it? I see a `<form>` with no input fields.

Comment: Thank you, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Only *successful* form controls (`input`, `button`, `textarea`, `select`) will provide data for a form submission.

The only form control you have is a submit button, but since it doesn't have a `name` attribute it won't be *successful*.

Add some form controls (possibly you want some `<input type="hidden" ...>` elements).

You may find [MDN's form guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms) useful as well as it's guide to [using forms with Express](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms).

Comment: Thanks for a quick reponse, I knew it was something wrong with my ejs file and that explains why